# Efficient way to protect image access by user

Tags: angularjs, node.js, rest, nginx

I am building a simple API using NodeJs, Angular and Nginx and I wondering which is the most efficient (and proper) way of serve public images to users independently.

So at this moment I was storing images directly in my database, so a certain user can only access to his own images. Nevertheless I would like to simply store the image path instead and save the file in a public folder in my server.

What is the best way to administrate the access to this folder?

Comment: You could send an authentication token with the request and validate that on the server

Answer (score 1):

You can use a seperate proxy for the images in your server like this:

```
location ~ ^/images/(.*)$ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /image_handler?image=$1;
}
```

Then you can restrict the access if the image file doesn't belong to the currently logged in user.